# Speed up console application, Concurrency? Parralell Programming?

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency

I have the following (simplified) console application:

```
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\Test");
FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.txt"); 
foreach(FileInfo file in Files )
{
  //Do Something
}
```

There are 200+ files in the filefolder. The processing of each file will take about 15 minutes.

My question is, is it possible for me to use concurrency/parallel programming to process more than on file at a time?

The kind of thing I am thinking is, to start a number of threads? and each one of them will process every 5th or so file in the files list.

All the file processing will be totally independent, so no risk of race condition.

If this is possible, are there limits to how many threads I can start, or any other limitations.

The kind of work that will be done is to load the contents of each file into a generic list, process it and iterate through the list numerous times

Comment: @Sayse it will load the contents into a generic list, perform some calculations on the data and write the results to a text file. A new output file will be created for each input file

Comment: it is the right job for parallel tasks

Comment: This is going to depend on where your bottleneck is.  If you are maxing your IO, for example, more threads will slow the process down.

Comment: @WDS so you mean these tasks can be carried out concurrently, but there is a limit ot the IO capacity - so I need to minimise this eg write in and out as little as possible, are in sequence? What is the approximate limit for IO? Each file has approx 12000 lines

Comment: Depends what you have.  IO on my computer is only maybe 50 MB per second realistically as I have cheap hard disks.  A RAID array will be much faster.  But it sounds like IO is not the bottleneck in your case -- a 12000 line file taking 15 minutes to process has got to be taking more time in the processing than in the read / write, so yeah, this sounds a likely candidate for parallel processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like it's a good job for [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992001(v=vs.110).aspx). It will provide you true parallelization because it can schedule each iteration to a different CPU core.

> If this is possible, are there limits to how many threads I can start,
>   or any other limitations.

I wouldn't spawn hundred of threads to perform this job, because it might happen that handling a lot of threads can take even more time because your CPU and disk will be too busy.

Answer (score 1):

```
Task based approach can be a solution, control your task based on available
resources.
        DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\Test");
        FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.txt");
        foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
        {
           //Check items in ConcurrentDictionary, if exceeds the limit -
           //wait here

            Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew((Object o) =>
            {
              //Do your work
            }, file);

            //Add items in ConcurrentDictionary;
        }
```